# ASP:Login : Password not autocomplete after enter Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, autocomplete, passwords

I used ASP:Login to take a Login form for my page.
Now I have 2 problem and I try to find a solution but ... @_@.
Now, I enter to login page. Type user, type password, then Enter

Problem 1 : Enter key not focus to Login button. It's mean, I must click to Login button to login. How can to set default button in this case ?

Problem 2 : Ok. Logged in. The browser (Chrome, Firefox ...) ask to save password. Ok. Saved.
And then, when I enter to login page in another time. The password will not autofill when I enter the username (browser still save username and password info).
Did I take a mistake in my setting or my code ? :(
My code :

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="transparent" Font-Names="Verdana" 
Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="147px" 
LoginButtonText="Đăng nhập" onloggingin="Login1_LoggingIn" 
RememberMeText="Nhớ password cho lần đăng nhập sau." 
TitleText="Đăng nhập hệ thống" Width="400px" 
FailureText="Đăng nhập không thành công!" 
HelpPageText="Anh, chị là khách hàng? " 
onauthenticate="Login1_Authenticate" 
PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Chưa nhập Password." 
UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Chưa nhập User Name." BorderColor="#339933" 
BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="border">
<HyperLinkStyle Font-Size="10pt" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
<LabelStyle Wrap="True" />
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" style="height:147px;width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2"  

                            style="color:White;background-color:#006D55;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;height:25px;white-space:nowrap; padding-left: 10px;">
                            Đăng nhập hệ thống</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">   
                            <br>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Height="22px" 
                                Width="250px" CssClass="border"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Chưa nhập User Name." 
                                ToolTip="Chưa nhập User Name." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Height="22px" 
                                TextMode="Password" Width="250px" CssClass="border" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Chưa nhập Password." 
                                ToolTip="Chưa nhập Password." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">   
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" 
                                Text="Nhớ password cho lần đăng nhập sau." AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  BackColor="#006D55" 
                                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="Login" 
                                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="White" Height="25px" 
                                Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1" Width="100%" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                            <hr />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HelpLink" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt">Anh, chị chưa có tài khoản ? </asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td align="left" colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Tạo tài khoản" 
                                onclick="ASPxButton1_Click" Width="100%"  
                                Font-Size="11pt" Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor="White" 
                                ForeColor="#006D55" Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <HoverStyle BackColor="#A6DDD1" Font-Bold="True">
                                </HoverStyle>
                                <Border BorderColor="#006D55" />
                            </dx:ASPxButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" 
    BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#284775" 
    Height="25px" Width="80px" />
<TextBoxStyle Font-Size="10pt" Height="22px" Width="150px" />
<TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" 
    ForeColor="White" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Wrap="False" />
```

```
    sp_compa.Service1 ws = new sp_compa.Service1();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
    Session["STATION_CODE"] = "";
    Session["COMP_CODE"] = "";
    Session["COMP_NAME"] = "";
    Session["UserName"] = "";
    Session["PassWord"] = "";
    Session.Timeout = 120;
}
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    string user = this.Login1.UserName.Trim();
    string password = this.Login1.Password.Trim();
    DataSet ds = sp.get_user_new(user, clsdb.identity);
    Session["dsuser"] = ds;
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        if (this.Login1.Password.ToUpper().Trim().Equals(row["PassWord"].ToString().ToUpper()))
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Session["UserName"] = user;
            Session["PassWord"] = password;
            Session["COMP_CODE_User"] = row["COMP_CODE"];
            if ((bool)row["KH"] == false)
                Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/ttkh.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    e.Authenticated = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for Problem 1 is to use Asp.Net panel and use it's Defau`enter code here`ltButton property.

For example,

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton = "LoginButton">
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0" style="height:147px;width:400px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2"  

                            style="color:White;background-color:#006D55;font-size:11pt;font-weight:bold;height:25px;white-space:nowrap; padding-left: 10px;">
                            Đăng nhập hệ thống</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td align="left" colspan="2">   
                                <br>   
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Height="22px" 
                                Width="250px" CssClass="border"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Chưa nhập User Name." 
                                ToolTip="Chưa nhập User Name." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" Height="22px" 
                                TextMode="Password" Width="250px" CssClass="border" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Chưa nhập Password." 
                                ToolTip="Chưa nhập Password." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">   
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" 
                                Text="Nhớ password cho lần đăng nhập sau." AutoPostBack="True" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server"  BackColor="#006D55" 
                                BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="Login" 
                                Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="11pt" ForeColor="White" Height="25px" 
                                Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1" Width="100%" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" colspan="2">
                            <hr />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HelpLink" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt">Anh, chị chưa có tài khoản ? </asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td align="left" colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="Tạo tài khoản" 
                                onclick="ASPxButton1_Click" Width="100%"  
                                Font-Size="11pt" Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor="White" 
                                ForeColor="#006D55" Height="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <HoverStyle BackColor="#A6DDD1" Font-Bold="True">
                                        </HoverStyle>
                                        <Border BorderColor="#006D55" />
                                    </dx:ASPxButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

In regards to problem 2, I do not know why your browser is not pushing password back to the text box.

Comment: Thanks for support.
In problem 2, I try it on many another PC but problem still on. On the first login, I chose save pass word but after that, the browser isnot pushing password back

Comment: Yeap. I put template to panel and set default button. Done problem 1. 
But problem 2 is ... @_@ ... I try any change but result is .... no change @_@